# Why does bs4 return tags and then an empty list to this find_all() method?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Looking at [US Census QFD](http://quickfacts.census.gov/qfd/states/48/48507.html) I'm trying to grab the race % by county. The loop I'm building is outside the scope of my question, which concerns this code:

```
url = 'http://quickfacts.census.gov/qfd/states/48/48507.html'
#last county in TX; for some reason the qfd #'s counties w/ only odd numbers
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

c_black_alone = soup.find_all("td", attrs={'headers':'rp9'})[0] #c = county %
s_black_alone = soup.find_all("td", attrs={'headers':'rp9'})[1] #s = state %
```

Which grabs the html element including its tags, not just the text within it:

```
c_black_alone, s_black_alone

(<td align="right" headers="rp9 p1" valign="bottom">96.9%<sup></sup></td>,
 <td align="right" headers="rp9 p2" valign="bottom">80.3%<sup></sup></td>)
```

Above ^, I only want the %'s inside the elements...

Furthermore, why does

```
test_black = soup.find_all("td", text = "Black")
```

not return the same element as above (or its text), but instead returns an empty bs4 ResultSet object? (Edit: I have been following along with the documentation, so I hope this question doesn't seem too vague...)

Comment: Why would you expect the second `find_all()` to return the first elements? There is no such text directly contained in those elements. Unless you use a regular expression, the second search is not going to match anything anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have actually also tried `test_black = soup.find_all("td", text = re.compile("Black"))` which also returns an empty ResultSet obj.  I was under the impression that because the text appears in the parent element, that it would find(_all) that element and return it...

Comment: Have I misunderstood something here? [bs4: text argument](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument)

Comment: A literal string value only matches the *whole* contents, not a partial match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the text from those matches, use `.text` to get *all* contained text:

```
>>> soup.find_all("td", attrs={'headers':'rp9'})[0].text
u'96.9%'
>>> soup.find_all("td", attrs={'headers':'rp9'})[1].text
u'80.3%'
```

Your `text` search doesn't match anything for two reasons:

1. A literal string only matches the *whole* contained text, not a partial match. It'll only work for element with `<td>Black</td>` as the *sole* contents.
2. It will use the [`.string` property](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string), but that property is only set if the text is the *only* child of a given element. If there are other elements present, the search will fail entirely.

The way around this is by using a lambda instead; it'll be passed the whole element and you can validate each element:

```
soup.find_all(lambda e: e.name == 'td' and 'Black' in e.text)
```

Demo:

```
>>> soup.find_all(lambda e: e.name == 'td' and 'Black' in e.text)
[<td id="rp10" valign="top">Black or African American alone, percent, 2013 (a)  <!-- RHI225213 --> </td>, <td id="re6" valign="top">Black-owned firms, percent, 2007  <!-- SBO315207 --> </td>]
```

Both of these matches have a comment in the `<td>` element, making a search with a `text` match ineffective.

Comment: This is excellent, thank you.  

I take it the output from the demo can have its 96.9% and 80.3% extracted using the same .text method you mention above?

Comment: I based my demo of the URL you gave in your question; the output I posted was entirely live. So yes, you can extract those values using `.text`.