# Python extract info from a local html file

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have this local website and I want to extract each line after

```
<font color='000000'> <u>PATTERN:</font>
```

Here is the page source, it's an output from the program ApproxMAP on google code:

```
<! Created by program ApproxMAP by Hye-Chung(Monica) Kum>
<HTML><font size=5 face='Helvetica-Narrow'><b>
<font color='000000'> Cluster Support= [Pattern=</font>
<font color='000000'> 50</font>
<font color='000000'> % : Variation=</font>
<font color='000000'> 20</font>
<font color='000000'> %]; Database Support= [Min= </font>
<font color='000000'> 1</font>
<font color='000000'>  seq: Max=</font>
<font color='000000'> 50</font>
<font color='000000'> %]</font>
<BR>
<font color='a9a9a9'> cluster=0 size=3</font>
<font color='000000'>   =<100:</font>
<font color='434343'> 85:</font>
<font color='767676'> 70:</font>
<font color='a9a9a9'> 50:</font>
<font color='c8c8c8'> 35:</font>
<font color='e1e1e1'> 20></font>
<BR>
<font color='000000'> <u>PATTERN:</font>
<font color='000000'> {1,} {2,3,} {4,5,} 
</font>
<font color='000000'> =</font>
<font color='000000'> 5</font>
<font color='000000'> </u></font>
<BR>
<font color='000000'> {</font>
<font color='000000'> 1</font>
<font color='cbcbcb'> 12</font>
<font color='000000'> }</font>
<font color='000000'> {</font>
<font color='cbcbcb'> 24</font>
<font color='000000'> }</font>
<font color='000000'> {</font>
<font color='7f7f7f'> 2</font>
<font color='7f7f7f'> 3</font>
<font color='cbcbcb'> 25</font>
<font color='000000'> }</font>
<font color='000000'> {</font>
<font color='cbcbcb'> 1</font>
<font color='7f7f7f'> 4</font>
<font color='7f7f7f'> 5</font>
<font color='000000'> }</font>
<font color='000000'> {</font>
<font color='cbcbcb'> 26</font>
<font color='000000'> }</font>
<BR>
<font color='000000'> <u>PATTERN:</font>
<font color='000000'> {9,10,} {11,} {12,13,} 
</font>
<font color='000000'> =</font>
<font color='000000'> 5</font>
<font color='000000'> </u></font>
<BR>
<font color='000000'> {</font>
<font color='717171'> 9</font>
<font color='989898'> 10</font>
<font color='000000'> }</font>
<font color='000000'> {</font>
<font color='d3d3d3'> 11</font>
<font color='000000'> }</font>
<font color='000000'> {</font>
<font color='404040'> 11</font>
<font color='000000'> }</font>
<font color='000000'> {</font>
<font color='404040'> 12</font>
<font color='989898'> 13</font>
<font color='000000'> }</font>
<BR>
<font color='000000'> TOTAL LEN=</font>
<font color='000000'> 10</font>
<BR>
<BR>
</b></font></html>
```

In this case, I want to extract the following:

```
{1,} {2,3,} {4,5,} 
{9,10,} {11,} {12,13,}
```

Here are some code I tried but none of them worked:

```
# First try
soup = BeautifulSoup('file:///H:/Approx_google_code/tiny20.html')
soup.findall('PATTERN:')

# Second try
re.search( "PATTERN:", 'file:///H:/Approx_google_code/tiny20.html')

# Third try
soup.body.findAll(text='PATTERN:')

# Forth try
soup.body.findAll(text=re.compile('PATTERN:'))
```

I've been stuck on this easy problem for so long that I started to wonder whether BeautifulSoup is the right direction. I'm totally new to HTML so any easy explanations / suggestions are welcomed, thanks.

I tried the example from [Why does bs4 return tags and then an empty list to this find_all() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369371/why-does-bs4-return-tags-and-then-an-empty-list-to-this-find-all-method) but got no results.

Comment: What's your output look like?

Comment: `soup.find_all(lambda e: 'PATTERN' in e.text)` will work; the `text` argument only works when there are *no other elements* in a tag.

Comment: Your HTML is otherwise badly malformed; the `<u>` element has no closing element `</u>`, for example.

Comment: I note that both `'html.parser'` and `'lxml'` as parsers give results for `soup.find_all(text=re.compile('PATTERN:'))` however.

Comment: Hi Steven, the output was ''NoneType' object is not callable',  'None',  '[ ]',  '[ ]', respectively.

Comment: Hi Martijin Pieters, `soup.find_all(lambda e: 'PATTERN' in e.text)` gave me `[ ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locate the element containing `PATTERN:` text, find the `font` parent and get the next `font` sibling element:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for elm in soup.find_all(text="PATTERN:"):
    print elm.find_parent("font").find_next_sibling("font").get_text(strip=True)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>> data = """
... <! Created by program ApproxMAP by Hye-Chung(Monica) Kum>
... <HTML><font size=5 face='Helvetica-Narrow'><b>
... <font color='000000'> Cluster Support= [Pattern=</font>
... <font color='000000'> 50</font>
... <font color='000000'> % : Variation=</font>
... <font color='000000'> 20</font>
... <font color='000000'> %]; Database Support= [Min= </font>
... <font color='000000'> 1</font>
... <font color='000000'>  seq: Max=</font>
... <font color='000000'> 50</font>
... <font color='000000'> %]</font>
... <BR>
... <font color='a9a9a9'> cluster=0 size=3</font>
... <font color='000000'>   =<100:</font>
... <font color='434343'> 85:</font>
... <font color='767676'> 70:</font>
... <font color='a9a9a9'> 50:</font>
... <font color='c8c8c8'> 35:</font>
... <font color='e1e1e1'> 20></font>
... <BR>
... <font color='000000'> <u>PATTERN:</font>
... <font color='000000'> {1,} {2,3,} {4,5,}
... </font>
... <font color='000000'> =</font>
... <font color='000000'> 5</font>
... <font color='000000'> </u></font>
... <BR>
... <font color='000000'> {</font>
... <font color='000000'> 1</font>
... <font color='cbcbcb'> 12</font>
... <font color='000000'> }</font>
... <font color='000000'> {</font>
... <font color='cbcbcb'> 24</font>
... <font color='000000'> }</font>
... <font color='000000'> {</font>
... <font color='7f7f7f'> 2</font>
... <font color='7f7f7f'> 3</font>
... <font color='cbcbcb'> 25</font>
... <font color='000000'> }</font>
... <font color='000000'> {</font>
... <font color='cbcbcb'> 1</font>
... <font color='7f7f7f'> 4</font>
... <font color='7f7f7f'> 5</font>
... <font color='000000'> }</font>
... <font color='000000'> {</font>
... <font color='cbcbcb'> 26</font>
... <font color='000000'> }</font>
... <BR>
... <font color='000000'> <u>PATTERN:</font>
... <font color='000000'> {9,10,} {11,} {12,13,}
... </font>
... <font color='000000'> =</font>
... <font color='000000'> 5</font>
... <font color='000000'> </u></font>
... <BR>
... <font color='000000'> {</font>
... <font color='717171'> 9</font>
... <font color='989898'> 10</font>
... <font color='000000'> }</font>
... <font color='000000'> {</font>
... <font color='d3d3d3'> 11</font>
... <font color='000000'> }</font>
... <font color='000000'> {</font>
... <font color='404040'> 11</font>
... <font color='000000'> }</font>
... <font color='000000'> {</font>
... <font color='404040'> 12</font>
... <font color='989898'> 13</font>
... <font color='000000'> }</font>
... <BR>
... <font color='000000'> TOTAL LEN=</font>
... <font color='000000'> 10</font>
... <BR>
... <BR>
... </b></font></html>
... """
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> 
>>> for elm in soup.find_all(text="PATTERN:"):
...     print elm.find_parent("font").find_next_sibling("font").get_text(strip=True)
... 
{1,} {2,3,} {4,5,}
{9,10,} {11,} {12,13,}
```

Note that, since I have `lxml` installed, `BeautifulSoup` uses it as an underlying parser. I've tried with `html.parser` also and it worked for me. `html5lib` does not work as the previous two. Anyway, specify the parser explicitly:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
```

or:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
```

Comment: Hi alecxe, I tried your code and tried specifying the parser but I got nothing for the ouput.

Comment: @Kyala okay, try to find the solution in the topic marked as duplicate. Good luck!

Comment: @Kyala you would not find the solution there, because it's not actually a duplicate. You should still be able to run the example code I've provided with specifying either `html.parser` or `lxml` as a parser. It worked for me as you see in the demo.