# Why does BS4 (from BeautifulSoup) return only [ ] when using the .select()?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

The following code only returns empty brackets. I have looked at this post [Why does bs4 return tags and then an empty list to this find_all() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369371/why-does-bs4-return-tags-and-then-an-empty-list-to-this-find-all-method) but it is different because I am not using the find_all(), rather .select(). Please note, I changed "nth-child" to "nth-of-type" to avoid an error.

```
    import bs4
    import requests
    res = requests.get('http://www.sharkresearchcommittee.com/pacific_coast_shark_news.htm')
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
soup.select('body > div > div:nth-of-type(2) > center > table > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(1) >td:nth-of-type(2) > p:nth-of-type(8) > strong:nth-of-type(1) > font')
```

The output is [ ]

Comment: ... Because there are 0 matches?

Comment: Note that `tbody` elements don't actually exist in the markup, they're added by browsers and parsers like `html5lib` (unlike `html.parser`).

Comment: @ Blender - thank you for your response. I took out the tbody and still got the same output

Answer (score 2):

It would probably have made more sense if you had told us what you're trying to match.  Because the reason you get no matches is obviously because your select doesn't have any matches.

Based on the rest of your select, I'm guessing you're in the wrong div at this point:

body > div > div:nth-of-type(2)

That DIV contains this text:

> The material contained on this Web site is shared as a public service
>   and to further the scientific goals of the Shark Research Committee. 
>   All text and images on this Web site are the exclusive property of the
>   Shark Research Committee....

I'm guessing you want to be in the div up from there and this is the selector you're probably after:

```
soup.select('body > div > div > center > table > tr > td:nth-of-type(2) > p:nth-of-type(8) > strong > font')
```

The above will get you:

```
[<font size="4">Ventura </font>, <font size="4">  </font>]
```

Didn't look into it in depth, but I'm sure there is a much better selection choice than what you're using to get the same thing.  But the above will likely get you what you're after.

Full code:

```
import bs4
import requests
res = requests.get('http://www.sharkresearchcommittee.com/pacific_coast_shark_news.htm')
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
print(repr(soup.select('body > div > div > center > table > tr > td:nth-of-type(2) > p:nth-of-type(8) > strong > font')))
```

Running:

```
markh@mob:~/stackoverflow/51256960$ python bs1.py 
[<font size="4">Ventura </font>, <font size="4">  </font>]
```

Comment: @ clockwatcher . I am under the impression I am copying the correct CSS Selector considering I right clicked over the text I wanted to select from the webpage ( the text was Venice...  I just want the location of the shark sighting) . I tried your code and it returned the same []. I thank you for your input.

Comment: @pes04 -- you must not have copied my selector correctly or edited it in some way. 
 I updated the comment with the full code.

Comment: your right, I am wrong @ clockwatcher, it returned the Ventura line. THank you!!

Answer (score 0):

It means it can't find any match.

It's either there's no such tag, but if you are sure that there is, then try using the `html5lib` or `lxml parsers`.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the error of no matches using .select, you can perform the following:

Open Inspect element or Developer tools

- **Chrome** `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `I` or `F12` or Right-Click Inspect Element
- **Opera** `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `C` or Right-Click Inspect Element
- **Safari**  `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `I`
- **Firefoz** `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `I` or `F12`

Note that for MAC you should use `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `I`

Once the Developer Tools are open, check for the element you would like to target.

Usually the element would have a class or id keyword(hopefully)

Grab the id or class, as shown below.

To grab the **id** ensure your code looks as follows: `soup.select('#CompanyInfo')`
To grab the **class** ensure your code looks as follows `soup.select('.CompanyInfo')`

Note: Than you can print only the text using `soup.select('.CompanyInfo')[0].getText()`
Don't forget to add the index since select return a list.

Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

`tbody` was the problem in my case.

I found it by adding selector levels one by one and detected that producing an empty list.